# How could i make the yticks`scale customized when i plot a bar in matplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I am a newbie in matplot.
as you can see in above fig,in my plot the values of some items are too small to make some sections of the bars is too low (just like the red section),so these sections are not very clearly to see.
How could i solve this problem?

Comment: Could you drop your code , please? that would be helpful

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you asking how to change the appearance of the data itself, or of the scale's ticks?

Comment: yes i want to change the scale of yticks, The length of the scale is uniform

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [matplotlib.pyplot.bar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), you can add the parameter `log`.
Example:

```
plt.bar(df.index, df[col].values, label=label, log=True)
```

or:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: Thack you for your help!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ3V0.png
But the reslut is still not enough clear for others

Comment: Maybe you can show what you would like? if you post also your code it would be easier to help

Comment: @Xianghui: What kind of scaling is that?

Comment: sorry my English is poor,maybe you can get my idea from this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmvGG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much！
This is what i want the plot looks like ：

[image: img]
my code:

```
time_ticks = np.arange(0,31,1)
ax_time.bar(x, msg_1_time, width=width, label='Msg1 time', color='r')
ax_time.bar(x, msg_3_time, bottom= msg_1_time, width=width, label='Msg3 time', color='g')
ax_time.bar(x, UL_Time, bottom=msg_3_time+msg_1_time, width=width, label='UL packet time', color='deepskyblue')
ax_time.bar(x, Idle_Time, bottom=UL_Time+msg_3_time+msg_1_time, width=width, label='Inactivity time', color='burlywood')
ax_time.set_xlabel('ECL',font)
ax_time.set_yticks(time_ticks)
ax_time.set_ylabel('Time (s)',font)

energy_ticks = np.arange(0,9,1)
ax_energy.bar(x, msg_1_energy, width=width, label='Msg1 energy', color='thistle')
ax_energy.bar(x, msg_3_energy, width=width, bottom= msg_1_energy, label='Msg3 energy', color='deepskyblue')
ax_energy.bar(x, UL_Energy, width=width, bottom=msg_3_energy+msg_1_energy, label='UL packet energy', color='lemonchiffon')
ax_energy.bar(x, Idle_Energy,width=width, bottom=UL_Energy+msg_3_energy+msg_1_energy, label='Inactivity energy',color='navajowhite')
ax_energy.set_xlabel('ECL',font)
ax_energy.set_yticks(energy_ticks)
ax_energy.set_ylabel('Energy (J)',font)
```